# Laravel Nova populate field with contents of another field on create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am defining some resources in Nova and I ran into a bit of a problem. I have a `Team` resource has the fields `name` and `display_name`. I only want `display_name` visible on the dashboard to work with but the way I have the `Team` model, `name` gets populated by turning `display_name` into a slug. Is there a way to populate `name` based on the contents of `display_name` with Nova when creating the resource?

```
Text::make('Name')->displayUsing(function(){
                return Str::slug($this->display_name, '_');
            })->hideFromIndex()
                ->hideFromDetail()
                ->hideWhenCreating()
                ->hideWhenUpdating(),

            Text::make('Display Name')
                ->rules('required', 'max:254')
                ->creationRules('unique:teams,name')
                ->updateRules('unique:teams,name,{{resourceId}}'),

            Textarea::make('Description')
                ->rules('required'),
```

This is what i've got now and it does give me the right output for `name` with resources that have already been created but when I try to create a new team I get this error:

[image]

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into 'teams' ('display_name', 'description', 'updated_at', 'created_at')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by use Laravel Mutator. Read it at here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Reference my code:

```
// app\Team.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Team extends Model
{
    public function setDisplayNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['display_name'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['name'] = Str::slug($this->display_name, '_');
    }
}

// app\Nova\Team.php
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Display Name','display_name'),
            Text::make('Name')->onlyOnIndex(),
            Text::make('Description'),
        ];
    }
```